# How to write a valid query (update with autoincrement variable)?

Tags: mysql

I want to write query like this:

```
SET @id := 0;
UPDATE table1
SET
    field1 = @id + 1,
    @id := @id + 1
```

And get error message:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
near '@id := @id + 1' at line 3
```

How write this query correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this, with the assignment and increment combined:

```
SET @id := 0;
UPDATE table1
SET
    field1 = (@id := @id + 1)
```

EDIT: you can even use an `ORDER BY` on such an UPDATE query to specify the order in which the numbers should be assigned.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a sequence. You could use [this implementation](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/04/02/stored-function-to-generate-sequences/) for example:

```
INSERT INTO seq VALUES('s1',1);
UPDATE table1 SET field1 = seq('s1');
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to break this into three statements instead of two.

```
SET @id := 0;
UPDATE table1
SET field1 = @id + 1;
SET @id := @id + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
declare @Count int
set @Count =0
update table1 set  @Count =column1=@Count +1
```